# Тире перед "если"?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, сложное-предложение

Недавно столкнулась со следующим предложением (перефразировано, но суть такая же):

"Он был привлекательным мужчиной () если бы они встретились при других обстоятельствах, она бы обязательно им заинтересовалась".

Можно и так:

"Он был привлекательным мужчиной () познакомься они раньше, она бы обязательно им заинтересовалась".

У меня в голове только тире, но это скорее на уровне ощущений, обосновать не могу. Если поставить запятую, теряется пауза после первой части, словно одно сплошное предложение. Возможно, да, стоило бы разделить точкой, но такой вот пример попался. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2):

(1) ***Он был привлекательным мужчиной** — (2) если бы они встретились при других обстоятельствах, (3) она бы обязательно им заинтересовалась.*

Тире здесь самый подходящий вариант. Как говорит Розенталь, "в настоящее время тире очень употребительный и многофункциональный знак препинания".

Тире необходимо **для разделения** предложения на две части — с помощью **запятой** это невозможно сделать (нужен более сильный знак).

Тире ставится **перед второй частью** сложного предложения (простые предложения 2 и 3), которая содержит **вывод, возможное следствие** из того, что сказано в первой части.  Это отдельное сложноподчиненное предложение с придаточным  условия (в нем говорится о действии, которое могло бы осуществиться).

**Интонационно** тире обозначает увеличенную **паузу и понижение** голоса (поэтому хочется поставить точку, как в конце предложения).

[О пониженной интонации при значении следствия, стр.234](https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf)

Правило: [Розенталь § 45. Тире в бессоюзном сложном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151#pp151)

Перед второй частью бессоюзного сложного предложения ставится тире, если в ней содержится следствие, результат либо вывод из того, о чем говорится в первой части: *Я бы в лётчики пошёл — пусть меня научат* (М.); *Достав из кармана одновременно и спички, и зажигалку, Крайнев зажёг шнуры — они вспыхнули* (Пап.);

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139384/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon---).

Answer (score 2):

**Ответ на комментарий**

1. Не умеете работать с интонацией, **так не беритесь за это**.  Ведь это вы мне написали: «А вы в курсе, что при тире следствия совсем другая интонация? Интонация первой части идёт вверх».  А потом: «Не особо умею правильно описывать интонацию».

**Примечание.** Я, кстати, тоже сначала решила, что здесь должно быть **повышение** тона по принципу **прямой** последовательности (событие/факт и следствие из него). Но потом согласилась с Кустовой: интонация здесь именно **присоединительная**, то есть **понижение** тона. Моя версия оказалась неверной – надо уметь прислушиваться к  мнению других и корректировать себя в некоторых случаях.

Я вообще говорю в ответе про интонацию только потому,  что **автор об этом спрашивает** и делает при этом правильное предположение. Интонация точки и присоединительного тире похожи – полное понижение голоса в обоих случаях, но пауза при тире заметно короче.

2. Вообще-то я не должна заниматься вашим образованием, если вы так себя ведете – сами книжки читайте.

***Лес (дрова) рубят – щепки летят.*** У Кустовой это п.4, стр.235.  «Условно-следственное и условно-временное значение. Восходяще-нисходящая интонация. Пунктуация – тире».

Другими словами: условие – событие (если); время – событие (когда). Я называю такое **тире разделительным** – нам важно разделить предложение на две части и противопоставить их, обозначив взаимообусловленность сообщений.

А при обозначении следствия (**присоединительное тире**) этого не нужно, так как информация дается как дополнительная (распространяет или поясняет тему).

3. **У Розенталя это** п. 4 (время) и пункт 5 (условие). А следствие – пункт 3 http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151#pp151 Это грамматическое решение для БСП из двух простых предложений.
4. В пунктуации важнее **объединять, а не различать.** Мы находимся в пространстве, где только **три основных знака** на письме **(четыре** – с учетом двойной функции тире), **четыре вида интонации** для них (определяется на слух) и **широкий** спектр значений. Здесь тоже нужен «маркер» для каждой группы, и таким маркером является  сам знак совместно с интонацией.
5. А пользователю надо разобраться **с семантикой**, то есть отнести конкретное значение к одной из групп.  Почему вы это не можете сделать? Зачем нужен точный анализ значения, если у нас всего **четыре** (а на письме только **три**) возможности.
6. **Запятая?** Я уже говорила в комментариях о том, что нам нужно разделить сложное предложение, состоящее из **трех** простых, на **две** части. Вам для этого Розенталь нужен с особым правилом? Вообще-то это называется делением на **смысловые блоки** и рассматривается как отдельная тема. А вы предлагает анализ БСП из двух (а не трех) простых предложений.

**Примечание.** Отвечать на ваши комментарии не буду, так как вы меня "дискредитируете", о чем сами написали прямым текстом.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139385/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon---).